# django - How to set default value for DecimalField in django 1.3?

Tags: python, django, django-models

One of my model's field looks like this:

```
total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=4,default=Decimal('0.0000'))
```

but when I run this command `python manage.py syncdb`, it shows this error:

```
NameError: name 'Decimal' is not defined
```

I have imported `from django.db import models`, do I need to import any other thing too?
Please Help!

Comment: Did you try at first `default=0.0` ? Also FYI the error says you need to import `Decimal()` as your PYTHONPATH does know it.

Comment: @MathieuMarques hi, default=0.00 or default=0.0 will be consider as float in django while creating first instance then you cannot add float with decimal for the first time, check type(total_amount) with default=0.00

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to import Decimal.

```
from decimal import Decimal
```

Answer (score 3):

```
total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=4, default=0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting error about default in Decimal Field you have to also pay your attension that max_digits e.x. 9 means 8 digit before dot and 1 digit after dot.

so max_digits=5 and default=Decimal('99999.0')  (6digits at all including trailing 0 at the end of decimal) is Invalid Decimal and Decimal('9999.0') is correct